# How To properly add Dist Folder to be tracked with Git when Using Sass

Tags: javascript, git, ubuntu, sass, terminal

Before I started using Sass I would just do "git add ." then I will upload to github.
But for this new project Im using Sass so I have my regular HTML & CSS in my "Dist" folder.

So for this new project I did "git add ." and it did all the node modules folder, json, and scss files but not my dist folder.

1. When tracking all files should I track all my node modules?
2. Or Should I only track my dist folder only?
3. If it should be all my files including node modules plus dist folder then what should I trpe in my ubuntu terminal?

I hope this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Update: Ok I was able to add gitignore file and it removed all of the node_modules from git but now the "dist" folder which contain my regular html css files is not being tracked.

I tryed to do git add . and check status but it keeps telling me "on branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `.gitignore` similar to [`github/gitignore Node.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore)

But you should also make sure if:

- you did not already added/committed `dist`
- or if its content is not already ignored by another .gitignore or exclude file

To check that:

```
cd dist
git check-ignore -v -- index.html
```

If it returns nothing, then it is not ignored.